# Closed under the metric topology

Tags: general-topology

Show that $B_{d}(x,\epsilon)=\left\{z\in X:d(x,z)\leq \epsilon \right\}$ is closed under the metric topology.

I'm new in topology so I have a few questions.

What's the intuition of metric topology ??And also what do we mean by closed under the metric space and how do we prove that ??

Answer (score 1):

By definition a closed set is a set whose complement is open.

However this definition is hard to  manipulate that why we usually use the sequential caracterisation for closed sets.

Intuition-wise $\mathbb{R}^2$ is your friend.

An open  set is like a ball "without its boundary"

a Closed set is like a ball "with its boundary"

the boundary notion has actually got a rigourous definition

We understand why closed is complement to open

But be careful intuition is sometimes misleading, especially for closed sets which can get pretty ugly (The Cantor ternary set ${\displaystyle {\mathcal {C}}} $).

Always stick to the definition and caracterizations.

Ok getting back to your question a metric topology is topology with a distance.

(Yes the general notion of a topology does not require a metric space!!)

As For the $B_{d}(x,\epsilon)=\left\{z\in X:d(x,z)\leq \epsilon \right\}$

Ill start with the tedious method (good for newcommers to topology where manipulating is essential).

$(E,d)$ a metric space with a topology

$B_{d}(x,\epsilon)=\left\{z\in X:d(x,z)\leq \epsilon \right\}$

$\Omega=E \setminus B_{d}$

Let us show that $\Omega$ is open

$\Omega= \left\{ z\in E \mid d(x,z)> \epsilon \right\}$

Let $z\in \Omega$

let $\eta$ be a positive real number such that  $\eta=d(x,z)-\epsilon$

$V=\left\{y\in E \mid d(y,z)< \eta\right\}$

$V$ is an open ball and by the triangular inequality $V \cap B_d=\emptyset$
hence $ V \subset \Omega$

we just proved that $\forall z \in \Omega, \quad \exists V \text{ an open ball } \mid x\in V  \text{and }V\subset \Omega$ that is the definition of open

ergo $\Omega$ is open therefore $B_d$ is closed. $QED$

A shorter way would be the sequential caractarization:
$$  F \text{ is closed } \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \forall (u_n)\in F^\mathbb{N} \ \ (\lim \limits_{n\to \infty} (u_n)=u \implies u\in F)$$